# Inno Setup - How to save a node in a specific line

Tags: xml, inno-setup

i need help with inno setup, i need to save some xml nodes in a specific line, but i dont know how to.

This is my code

```
procedure SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
//    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
//      MsgBox('Install the software. ' +
//        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
//    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.text := AValue;
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('Install the software', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  XMLFile: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (PageId = wpFinished) then
  begin
    XMLFile := ExpandConstant('{pf}\Hell\0\Config.xml');
    if FileExists(XMLFile) then
    begin
      SaveValueToXML(XMLFile, '//@param', PEdit.Text);  //PEdit.text is from a custom input text box in the installer, ignore.
      SaveValueToXML(XMLFile, '//@path',
        ExpandConstant('{reg:HKCU\SOFTWARE\Craps,InstallPath}\Test.exe'));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stuffs>
        <stuff ident="555" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Other thing\Other.exe" param="-alive" display="1" priority="0"/>
        <stuff ident="666" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Craps\test.exe" param="-dead" display="1" priority="0"/>    
</stuffs>
```

The problem is that my script always write in the first line. What i need is to always save the nodes in the line that start with `<stuff ident="666"`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use the [`setAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method insted of setting `text` property. Here is a procedure for modifying node attribute values:

```
procedure SaveAttributeValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AAttribute, 
  AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, 
      mbError, MB_OK);  
  end;
end;
```

And here is how to query a node whose `ident` parameter value is 666 and whose `param` attribute value will be changed to `-alive`:

```
SaveAttributeValueToXML('d:\File.xml', '//stuffs/stuff[@ident=''666'']',
  'param', '-alive');
```

For more information about the XPath query used here refer e.g. to [`this article`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2007/03/13/quick-tip-using-xpath-to-find-nodes-by-attribute-value.aspx).