# Inno setup: how to replace a string in XML file?

Tags: xml, inno-setup

The following (in quote) is the content of a XML file which is part of my package.
I'd like to replace the value of `c:\path\myapp.exe` during the installation (with the real path where the user chose to install the application.
Is that possible? How to?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType">
   <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
      <listEntry value="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.launchGroup"/>
   </listAttribute>
   <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SCOPE" value="${none}"/>
   <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="c:\path\myapp.exe"/>
   <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="${resource_loc}"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Comment: Actually I can treat this file as a regular text file.

Comment: You can call the procedure I wrote there like `SaveAttributeValueToXML('C:\File.xml', '//launchConfiguration/stringAttribute[@key=''org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION'']',
  'value', 'C:\NewPath\File.exe');`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best option is to use the XML DOM to select and edit the required node [as TLama suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719374/588306).

Alternatively, you can install a template file with a known string in the location you want to replace.
The file can then be read as a string, modified and written back out again using something like:

```
[Code]
procedure WriteAppPath;
var
    FileData: String;
begin
    LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\app.xml'), FileData);
    StringChange(FileData, 'XXXXXMARKERXXXXX', ExpandConstant('{app}'));
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\app.xml'), FileData, False);
end;
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19313517/588306) about doing the same thing en masse to an INI file.

Comment: The template idea is much better for its simplicity.

Comment: Consider using `StringChangeEx` for multi-byte support. `StringChange` has been deprecated.